# How one can conclude $S\subseteq \{0,1\}^m$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, pigeonhole-principle

While looking at a solution to a math problem, I came across this, let $f:\mathbb N\to \{0,1\}$ be a function such that  $$f(x)=\cases{1\quad\text{if $x$ is balanced}\\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise.}}$$

I won't explain what is a balanced number because it's irrelevant to the purpose of my question. Now consider $$S=\{(f(n+1),f(n+2),...,f(n+m))\mid n\in \mathbb N\}$$

Here the solution reads : $S\subseteq \{0,1\}^m$ and $\mid \{0,1\}^m\mid =2^m<\mid\mathbb N \mid $ hence by the pigeonhole principal $\exists a\ne b$ such that $f(a+n)=f(b+n), \forall n\le m$.

But I don't know how one can conclude $S\subseteq \{0,1\}^m$ I mean $S$ should be infinite because  $n$ runs over all the natural numbers.

Comment: Note that the only possible values for $f(x)$ are $0$ and $1$, not all the naturals. Sets only contain unique elements, so the set $\{0,1,1\}=\{0,1\}$. Most of these elements will be identical.

Comment: $\{(0,1),(1,1),(1,1)\}=\{(0,1),(1,1)\}$?

Comment: Yes, $\{(0,1),(1,1),(1,1)\}=\{(0,1),(1,1)\}$. All sets work this way. Note that you've concluded that the image should be infinite because the domain is. This is not the case as any constant function shows.